# jquerymobile Add select menus dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a set of dropboxes
code is

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <!--<legend>&nbsp;</legend>-->
    <select name="select-widget" id="select-widget">
        <option value="Widget">Widget</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select-nbl" id="select-nbl">
        <option value="NBL">NBL</option>
        <option value="HSM">HSM</option>
        <option value="TERR">TERR</option>
        <option value="KEY_ACCOUNT">KEY ACCOUNT</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select-level-focus" id="select-level-focus">
        <option value="LEVEL">LEVEL</option>
        <option value="FOCUS">FOCUS</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select-wdg" id="select-wdg">
        <option value="WDG">WDG</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select-wds" id="select-wds">
        <option value="WDS">WDS</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

No I want to remove exixsting selectbox or add new select box to it on change of "select-nbl" or "select-levelfocus"

How to do it using jquerymobile

Comment: Can you be more precise? When the select-nbl or the select-levelfocus changed, what should appear/disappear, and where?

Answer (score 0):

This has little to do with jQuery mobile, that's merely a mobile framework. The event listeners and DOM manipulation you want to do here is still handled by jQuery.

Anyways, how do you do it?

Well, you have your event listeners:

```
$('#select-nbl').change(function() {
    #Do something
});
```

And you can hide stuff:

```
$('#select-wdg').parents('.ui-select').hide();
```

The use of parents() is to take care of the extra styling jQuery mobile puts in there.

You can't easily add select boxes to jQuery mobile, but if they're hidden, you can show them.

```
$('#select-wdg').parents('.ui-select').show();
```

All this is action: http://jsfiddle.net/luhn/Vgc4g/9/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. 
Upto some extent is a gr8 solution.. 
but when we need to remove first or last element it gives problem for rounded corners.. 
if we need to remove more than one select box sequentially from start or end it will keep on giving corners problem.

I am working on it remove corners problem... i.e making css for last element.